# Find similar style like selection in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, microsoft-word-2010

I pasted a web page into word ( from the internet by copy+paste)

the result is here

[image]

However , I want to change the blue background color.

How can I replace in my document , ONLY SECTIONS with that color ? I dont know what the color is.
I select with the mouse a small selection , and I want all the similar styles in the document to be  , let's say, red background-color.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was pasted from a web page, so HTML styling is applied. I find that when I select the whole web page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and then copy and paste into Word, the blue paragraph shading does not appear.

If you want to retain the paragraph shading and just change it to a different color, you need to convert the HTML styling to Word styles:

Click the lower right corner of the Styles panel to open the Styles pane, then on Options. Select styles in the current document and tick the box to show Paragraph level formatting.

[image]

Now you see a list of styles that have been converted from the HTML styling. If you hover over them, you see a pop-up with the formatting details of each style. The blue background has been applied as a paragraph shading. You can now select the down-arrow on each style and select Modify Style > Format button > Border ... > Shading Tab and set a different paragraph shading color for that style.

[image]

You need to do that for each style that has the blue background applied.

Answer (score 1):

In the search and replace dialog click the Find What field and then select the Format button on the bottom and select Style... at the style selection dialog you can select the style you want to change from.

Same goes for the "Replace with" field.

The only problem you may encounter is that you'll have to properly assign styles to your text before you can use this feature.

This is an image showing the dialog:

[image]

Comment: You will have to know exactly which style to search for. So, first you need to identify the style names. It's a bit more complex than "Heading 1", since the content was pasted from HTML with complex formatting applied. Also, to use your suggestion, one would need to set up new styles to use as replacements. These styles will then have to have all the OTHER styling attributes exactly like the original style. The file shows about a dozen different converted styles with the color background.  A bit more than a simple find-and-replace, I'm afraid.